# HTML 5 - Using it in Production

Tags: html

Can I start using Html 5 on our websites? Or is it too early to use it?
I see that Google is using Html 5 for their images site. If google can use it, I guess, we too can.

Comment: Yes you can use HTML5. Today, please do.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399016/html5-where-to-start/7399075#7399075) you can find many useful links about many aspects of HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Depending on who you ask, HTML5 is already ready, or it won't be ready until 2022" this was quoted from Google developer advocate Mark Pilgrim at the WWW2010 conference..

you can have a look at this [post](http://www.infoworld.com/t/internet/google-official-reaffirms-html5-readiness-444) also this [post](http://www.itmontreal.ca/blog/2011/08/html-5-ready-use/) and read some info about HTML5 whether ready or not

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 is many things. If you're asking, "Is every feature of HTML5 ready for the web?" then the answer is and will be *no* for a long time.

Instead, if you're asking "Can I use these cool HTML5 things like `<section>` elements, canvas, CSS3, custom fonts, and local storage?" then the answer is *yes*. The best source to guage support of HTML5 features is [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/), which also includes links to [shims or polyfills](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/) for browsers which don't support the feature.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: yes, you **should**.

Please read [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/12/10/why-we-should-start-using-css3-and-html5-today/), and [here](http://www.standardista.com/yes-you-can-start-using-html5-today/).